# Issue in adding one table row to a table when similar multiple tables are present on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, tablerow

I've a form in which containing one `<div>` tag and the HTML within it. This is what I've when page loads. Then through AJAX I'm appending the same block(i.e. ) to the existing one. In every `<div>` tag there is one `<table>` and in that `<table>` I've a button with **class products**. After clicking on it I'm calculating the no. of rows present in that table only and assigning the id to the newly added row. But the issue I'm facing is when I add multiple such tables using AJAX and click on add button of any table it's calculating the total no. of rows present in all tables and adding that much no. of rows to the table in which I clicked add button. This shouldn't have to happen. It has to add only one row. I've created a jsfiddle for your reference. In fiddle I've put in static HTMl so it's working fine over there but on my local machine when I add multiple tables using AJAX I'm getting wrong no. of rows added.For example if I added three tables and click on add button of first table then it's adding four rows to that table. Why it's counting the total no. of rows present in all the tables present on a page?Is there any need to improve my script? My script is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.products').click(function () {
    var table_id = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');            
    var no = table_id.match(/\d+/)[0];            
    //var first_row = $(this).closest('table').find('tbody tr:first').attr('id');
    var first_row = $('#'+table_id).find('tbody tr:first').attr('id');
    var new_row = $('#'+first_row).clone();
    var tbody = $('tbody', '#'+table_id);
    var n = $('tr', tbody).length  + 1;
    new_row.attr('id', 'reb' + no +'_'+ n);

    $(':input', new_row).not('.prod_list').remove();
    $('select', new_row).attr('name','product_id_'+no+'['+n+']');
    $('select', new_row).attr('id','product_id_'+no+'_'+n);
    $('<button style="color:#C00; opacity: 2;" type="button" class="close delete" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>').appendTo( $(new_row.find('td:first')) );
    tbody.append(new_row);
    $('.delete').on('click', deleteRow);
   });   
});
```

Following is jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/vrNAL/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean to query is this:

```
var tbody = $('#' + table_id + ' tbody');
```

Instead of:

```
var tbody = $('tbody', '#' + table_id);
```

From the jQuery documentation, I don't think selectors work this way.

Comment: I tried your trick but still the result is same. No change at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some strange things with the IDs here. why are you getting the IDs and selecting the sleemts with that, instead of using the selected elements directly?

Example:

```
var table_id = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');   
var table = $("#" + table_id);
```

Is the same as just

```
var table = $(this).closest('table');
```

and

```
var first_row = $('#'+table_id).find('tbody tr:first').attr('id');
var new_row = $('#'+first_row).clone();
```

is the same as:

```
 var new_row = table.find('tbody tr:first').clone();
```